# Mouse support on console

Tags: linux, mouse, terminal, debian

Can someone please remind me which package I need to install to use mouse in the standard (non X-windows) terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GPM (General Purpose Mouse)](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gpm.xml) is probably the (ancient) package you're thinking of.  Haven't heard anything about it lately.

There should be a version available in the [standard Debian repositories](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gpm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: That looks right.  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=267742

Comment: oddly enough, i can't remember the last time i used gpm.  i can remember the *first* time i used it; wasn't long after my first linux install.

Comment: not that "oddly" IMO! :D